# Can the articles be omitted (in those 2 cases)?

Tags: grammar, articles, style

**I have two sentences where I am not sure, whether I can omit an article or not. This is maybe bordering on stylistic choice:**

---

"*The rising sea quenched the fires of the last great war and the remnants of yesterday became islands in an ocean of oblivion. And*

- *last shelter for survivors clinging to life.*" **[No article]**
- ***the** last shelter for survivors clinging to live.*"
- ***one** last shelter for survivors clinging to live.*"
- ***a** last shelter for survivors clinging to life.*"

---

"*A world without pastures, without flocks, without*

- *a god.*"
- *god.*"

Notice: I'm *not* using *God* as the Christian name/adress for *the* God (like "please, God, help me"), but referring to it as Generic term, like

- a town without (a) maior
- a story without (a) hero
- a crime without (a) victim

In German the articles would be omitted in those cases.

Comment: I think you do need an article in all these cases. The article can be omitted in certain cases (e.g. without end, without purpose), but not usually. Thackeray's subtitle for _Vanity Fair_ was 'A novel without a hero'.

Comment: In the title, it should read "these", not "those". "Those" suggests we've already seen the cases.

Comment: Shelter can be non-countable: "I need shelter". But using "one last shelter" reads better IMO: it emphasises the loss of other places of shelter. And in the second example, why not "gods" to match the other nouns?

Answer (score 0):

I agree that with these options, it's going to be a stylistic choice thing.

In you first sentence, "and last shelter" would have a certain archaic dramatic feel to it in the way that a medieval drama would be narrated. On a different vein, "the last shelter" might suggest that this shelter is literally "the last" whereas "one/a last shelter" would seem to only suggest scarcity.

In the second sentence, I think a monotheistic would respond to "without god" with empathy, thinking it conveyed "oh, these people lack our sense of religion". But using "a god" would allow more of a scholarly eye at the setting where one would consider this place to be one of great practicality or great seriousness where religion/"greater meaning" isn't something they have time for or interest in.

Comment: 'Without any god' would make the meaning clearer.

Comment: It's OK to omit the article when the noun is plural, but I'm assuming that most English speakers, believers or not, would assume _god_ without any article or determiner to refer to God.

Comment: @Porkfu **Monotheistic** is an adjective, not a noun. No idea what you mean by **allow more of a scholarly eye at the setting**.  Prefer **In a different vein** to **on a different vein**. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+a+different+vein%2Cin+a+different+vein&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20a%20different%20vein%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20a%20different%20vein%3B%2Cc0